# Why is RYE the answer to "Grass over pretty Cambridge backs"?

Tags: cryptic-clues, explanation

The clue is:

> Grass over pretty Cambridge backs

The answer is RYE. I get the grass part, but what is the connection in the rest of the clue? This is from the Saturday Telegraph Cryptic, clue no. 29562

Answer (score 23):

"Grass" is the definition of the answer.

"Over pretty Cambridge backs" is the wordplay, in which "backs" means "last letters of the preceding words."

R from "over" + Y from "pretty" + E from "Cambridge" = RYE, a type of grass.

Comment: Thank you! I got it myself just after I posted it. Thanks again

Comment: If this answer solved your problem, you can Accept it by clicking on the checkmark to the left.

Comment: Why not "sryes" then (other than it not making sense)? Or "ye" since the grass is supposed to be on backs of the "pretty Cambridge" and "over" is not part of the pretty Cambridge. I don't think this riddle makes any sense (Is this comment not appropriate for this site?)

Comment: @s.harp: Are you familiar with British cryptic crosswords?  They have a lot of well-established conventions, and in that context, this clue makes sense and is quite clean.  Read as a riddle without that context, I agree, this would be quite ambiguous.

Comment: @s.harp In other context which may not be obvious to non-British readers (and possibly only to a subset of British readers) "the Backs" is an area of the city of Cambridge (the UK one) beside the river Cam, consisting of meadow land to a large degree, although perhaps not much ryegrass https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Backs